# How to let the regressor in the pipeline unpack the parameters?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I am using scikit-learn pipeline to cut down the steps of writing repetitive code. However I can't see to figure out the way to write a code that unpack the parameters for each regressor.

Before using Pipeline, I write a class to unpack the parameters. That works just fine though I do believe there is a better way to go with this.

I don't want to keep writing manually the parameters

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
pipe_et = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = Seed))
pipe_rf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), XGBRegressor())
```

This is an example of the parameters I want to be unpacked

```
rf_params = {'n_estimators': 1000, 'n_jobs': -1, 'warm_start': True, 'max_features':2}
```

There is no error. I don't want to do extra labor work but I expect `**params` to work but I don't know how to proceed with that. Please help me with my coding style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format the parameters of the estimator using `__` so that it can be fed as params for pipeline. I have written a small function that can take pipeline and parameters for the estimator, then it would return the appropriate params for the estimator.

Try this example:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pipe_rf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RandomForestRegressor())

rf_params = {'n_estimators': 10, 'n_jobs': -1, 'warm_start': True, 'max_features':2}

def params_formatter(pipeline, est_params):
    est_name = pipeline.steps[-1][0]
    return {'{}__{}'.format(est_name,k):v for k,v in est_params.items()}


params = params_formatter(pipe_rf, rf_params)
pipe_rf.set_params(**params)

# Pipeline(memory=None,
#          steps=[('standardscaler',
#                  StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)),
#                 ('randomforestregressor',
#                  RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, criterion='mse',
#                                        max_depth=None, max_features=2,
#                                        max_leaf_nodes=None,
#                                        min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
#                                        min_impurity_split=None,
#                                        min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
#                                        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
#                                        n_estimators=10, n_jobs=-1,
#                                        oob_score=False, random_state=None,
#                                        verbose=0, warm_start=True))],
#          verbose=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just loop through your `pipe_rf` object and get the parameters like this:

```
for i in pipe_rf:
    print (i.get_params())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'copy': True, 'with_mean': True, 'with_std': True}
{'base_score': 0.5, 'booster': 'gbtree', 'colsample_bylevel': 1, 'colsample_bynode': 1, 'colsample_bytree': 1, 'gamma': 0, 'importance_type': 'gain', 'learning_rate': 0.1, 'max_delta_step': 0, 'max_depth': 3, 'min_child_weight': 1, 'missing': None, 'n_estimators': 100, 'n_jobs': 1, 'nthread': None, 'objective': 'reg:linear', 'random_state': 0, 'reg_alpha': 0, 'reg_lambda': 1, 'scale_pos_weight': 1, 'seed': None, 'silent': None, 'subsample': 1, 'verbosity': 1}
```

Hope this helps!